# My website is localized, but I'm having trouble displaying the current date in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datetime, asp.net-4.0

I'm not a programmer, but I developed a small company website in Visual Studio.  I want to display the date -- in specific culture format -- on the master pages.  I have this at the top of one of my regular aspx pages:

```
  <%@ Page Title="USS Vision Control Panel Build" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Services/Services.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="controlpanels.aspx.vb" Inherits="controlpanels" culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="auto" %>
```

I've followed a lot of ASP tutorials on the web, and the only code that has displayed properly on my page is the following:

```
  <p><%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
```

The above-code results in this:

```
  1/18/2012 5:17:36 AM
```

The problem is that I'm in USA Eastern time, and the time came out in Pacific time.  I think I don't want it to include the time, since the time is static and it's the wrong time zone, and it's not updating, second by second.  So in summation, I think I'd rather just include the date.  It seems more professional for my site.

Does anybody know what I can do to resolve this?

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Jason Weber

Comment: Are you sure that you select USA Eastern time on your PC settings?

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) post from MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Mesiesta, and Amar.  Diamond, Paul, and User all gave really good answers.  I learned a lot in the process, and ended up using a version of Diamond's solution.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the current date without time.

```
DateTime.Today.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

Running it produces the output:

`1/18/2012`

Comment: It will be date from the server, not from the client.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, Diamond.  When I input that code, it underlines CultureInfo in blue and says I have to Generate 'Class CultureInfo' which I tried, but it won't let me.  Then I chose the other option, to generate a new class, and Visual Studio made CultureInfo.vb for me in my root, but that doesn't work either.  It also gives me an error with the ; at the end, saying 'end of statement expected'.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, and thank you sincerely for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Try typing `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` instead of just `CultureInfo`. Also, I failed to read your example sufficiently well to realise you are using VB and not C#. Remove the semi-colon from the end of the statement. I will update my answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Diamond -- no problems!  I experimented in other languages in IE, and they displayed in their language.  I changed it to Longdatepattern, and it's absolutely perfect!  Thank you again for taking the time to help me out, Diamond -- I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a format string as a parameter in your call to `.ToString()`

e.g.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")
```

yields:-

```
18-Jan-2012
```

At least today, anyway.

**See this article for more information on format options.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Note that any date that comes from the server will be in the local time of the server.

If you want to report the client date, it may be a lot easier to go for a Javascript solution ( which will use the date on your user's computer ).

Comment: If you want to set it using javascript, then you could do something like this, where <control_id> is the id of the control you want to display the date.
`var date = new Date();
document.getElementById('<control_id>').value = date.getDate();`

Comment: That works very well, Paul.  Thank you for that solution!  I'd like to get a little fancier, if possible, and make the date show up per the end-user's location.  So if they're in Germany, I'd like it to put the German date on there.  All of my files have  culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="auto" at the top line.  Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question, Paul; it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: I figured it out, Paul ... how to get the longdate format localized.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To format the string correctly you can use:

```
<p><%= DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %></p>
```

Which will give you 01/18/2012(Note the capitalization of 'M').

If you want to show the local time based on the users location, not the server time, you could use.

```
<p><%= DateTime.Now.ToLocalString.ToString() %></p>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi User.  Thanks for your response!  When I try this:

Comment: Hi User.  When I try your solution, the error message comes up in Visual Studio saying 'LocalString' is not a member of 'Date' and it's underlined in blue as an error, and the page doesn't display.  Any suggestions?  And thank you for taking the time to respond!  I do appreciate your help!

Comment: User, your first solution worked great!  I would like the time/date to be displayed per the end-user's settings.  So if they're in Germany, I'd like it to show the German date and time.  That's why I tried your second solution, but it gave me the error message I described above.  Thank you again for your time in helping me out!

Comment: Make sure you are using "ToLocalString" not "LocalString".